# Saving api response to State using useState and Axios (React JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm having an issue when trying to save to State an axios API call. I've tried
[useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately) 's answer and many other and I can't get the state saved. This is not a duplicate, because I've tried what the accepted answer is and the one below and it still doesn't work.
Here's the (rather simple) component. Any help will be appreciated

```
export const Home = () => {
    const [widgets, setWidgets] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get('/call-to-api')
            .then((response) => {
                const data = response.data;
                console.log(data); // returns correctly filled array
                setWidgets(widgets, data);
                console.log(widgets); // returns '[]'
            });
    }, []); // If I set 'widgets' here, my endpoint gets spammed
    return (
        <Fragment>
            {/* {widgets.map((widget) => { // commented because it fails
                <div>{widget.name}</div>;
            })} */}
        </Fragment>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow, first thing first the setting call is incorrect you must use spread operator to combine to array into one so change it to `setWidgets([...widgets, ...data]);` would be correct (I assume both `widgets` and `data` are Array)

second, react state won't change synchronously

```
        .then((response) => {
            const data = response.data;
            console.log(data); // returns correctly filled array
            setWidgets(widgets, data);
            console.log(widgets); // <--- this will output the old state since the setWidgets above won't do it's work till the next re-render
```

so in order to listen to the state change you must use `useEffect` hook

```
useEffect(() => {

   console.log("Changed Widgets: ", widgets)

}, [widgets])
```

this will console log anytime widget changes

the complete code will look like this

```
export const Home = () => {
    const [widgets, setWidgets] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get('/call-to-api')
            .then((response) => {
                const data = response.data;
                setWidgets([...widgets, ...data])
            });
    }, []); 

    
    useEffect(() => {

        console.log("Changed Widgets: ", widgets)

    }, [widgets])



    return (
        <Fragment>
            {/* {widgets.map((widget) => { // commented because it fails
                <div>{widget.name}</div>;
            })} */}
        </Fragment>
    );
};
```

Comment: Ok, this was super helpful.I didn't even know I could use more than one useEffect() in each Component. 
I'm still having issues rendering to the browser, but I believe that's MY problem.
 Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
setWidgets(data);
```

istead of

```
setWidgets(widgets, data);
```

Comment: Didn't help. I've pulled that modification from the answer to the question I linked, but didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

Your widgets.map() probably fails because there isn't much to map over when the component is being rendered.

You should update it with a conditional like so, just for clarity:

```
widgets.length>0 ? widgets.map(...) : <div>No results</div>
```

And your call to setWidgets() should only take one argument, the data:

```
setWidgets(data)
```

or if you want to merge the arrays use a spread operator (but then you need to add widgets as the dependency to the useEffect dependency array.

```
setWidgets(...widgets, ...data)
```

You might also have to supply the setWidgets hook function to the useEffect dependency array.

Let me know if this helps..

Comment: Unfortunately this approach doesn't help. Those 'widgets' are the content of the whole site, so can't skip over them. But @kak-sarkar 's answer helped me.
Appreciate the feedback!

Comment: @MartinScola No worries. The conditional was more meant as a failsafe for when the data is not yet loaded or won't load at all (API downtime for example). But that could be implemented in a multitude of ways. Happy coding!